# GAE transaction exceptions

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

**ServletA**:

- retrieves in a query a set of objects (around 2000) and then runs a weight function to choose one object and update it.
- all that is within a trasaction so it'll get an exception if the objects were changed

**ServletB**:

- each object is being updated every 15 secs by robot clients

So the record set that has been retrieved in ServletA is being updated every *2000/15 = 133 millsec*.
Will it ever succeed to update the object without interruption?

Comment: i could maybe split the object to two objects one changed by servletA and one by servletB and have the transaction only in servletA... I wish GAE would have the possiblity to define apps which can run on only one VM - not all apps are global!

Comment: Do you expect this situation to occur in your real-life application? Perhaps you should look into DoS protection: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/dos.html

Comment: come on, getting an update from a robot client every 15 sec is trivial to many applications (financial for example)

Answer (score 1):

ServletA will only throw an exception if the selected "best" room was updated after it was retrieved from the datastore, before it was persisted.

If any of the other 1999 entities were modified, it won't matter since you're not modifying them at all.